# kotlin coroutine parent child relationship

Tags: kotlin, parent-child, viewmodel, coroutine, cancellation

can anyone explain whats the difference between these 3 coroutines from the viewModelScope?

```
        viewModelScope.launch {
            launch {}
            launch {}
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            viewModelScope.launch {}
            viewModelScope.launch {}
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            coroutineScope {
                launch {}
            }
            coroutineScope {
                launch {}
            }
        }
```

im pertty sure for the first one, the 2 child coroutines are launched and if one produces an exception without handling it will propogate up to parent and the other will get canceled and the parent coroutine will be canceled at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Most coroutine builder functions like `coroutineScope()`, `withContext()`, `launch()`, etc. provide a `CorouineScope` as `this` and this scope could be considered "the current" coroutine. If we use this object to launch new coroutines, that means they become children of the current coroutine. If we use another coroutine scope, then new coroutines are children of that coroutine scope and usually are unrelated to the current coroutine.

That means:

1. `launch {}` - it launches a new coroutine as a child of the current coroutine.
2. `viewModelScope.launch {}` - new coroutine is a child of `viewModelScope`, it is unrelated to the current coroutine. In your specific case that new coroutine is a sibling of the calling coroutine.
3. `coroutineScope { launch {} }` - this is pretty much the same as 1.